# Problem with momentJs using utc and startOf around midnight

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, utc

I need to have the 00:00 of the current day in utc and timestamp so i do something like that:

```
moment().utc().startOf('day').valueOf()
```

I see that somebody suggest to use :

```
moment.utc().startOf('day').valueOf()
```

but I didn't find the differences...

Anyway, my problem is another: I work in +1 offset so my problem is when I try to take the midnight (startOf('day')) and the local hour time is between 00:00 and 01:00 I have the midnight of the previous day.

here some console log to be clare:

```
console.log("test1", moment().format())
>"test1", "2021-11-24T00:21:52+01:00"

console.log("test2", moment.utc().format())
>"test2", "2021-11-23T23:21:52+00:00"

console.log("test3", moment().utc().format())
>"test3", "2021-11-23T23:21:52+00:00"
```

as you can see if the local time is 00:21 the utc is 23:21 and if I try to keep the startOf('day') I will have as result the midnight of the day before.

```
console.log("test4", moment().startOf('day').format())
>test4", "2021-11-24T00:00:00+01:00"

console.log("test5", moment().utc().startOf('day').format())
>"test5", "2021-11-23T00:00:00+00:00"
```

**I need to use the UTC and the startOf**

How can I resolve the problem to have also the current day if I try to catch it between 00:00 and 01:00?  any idea?

and the same problem can be between 00:00 and different time zone not only +1

if for example, I would be in a +2 zone my problem would be shifted between 00:00 and 02:00

Thanks

Comment: So your after the start of a UTC date, based on the locale time, even if the UTC date is the previous day?.

Comment: ^ If so -> `moment(moment().startOf('day').format().slice(0,19)+'+00:00').format()`

Comment: meaning you don't actually want UTC.

Comment: QnD: `new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')).toISOString()`.

Comment: @Keith exact I need the start of the current day even if the UTC give me the previous day

Comment: Ok, so does the snippet I gave work as expected?

Comment: @Keith, I didn't use, I found another solution, just with something more or less like that if the if (moment().diff(mydate.utc().startOf('day').format("MM-DD-YYYY"), 'days') !== 0)) {moment().add(myDate.utcOffset(), 'minutes').utc() else MyDate

Comment: I think a "nearestStartOf" would do the trick. It's something to implement, but you wouldn't care anymore with a 2 hours timezone offset